# How to get three-dots action menu in Control API 2.0 based app?

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am using the Control API 2.0 on a Smart Watch 2 loosely based on the SampleAdvancedControlExtension demo from the Sony SDK. In the gallery view, users can view an item in detail. In this view, I want to activate the three-dot action-menu button on the smart phone. How would I do this? When I press the three-dot button, my extension app receives this event: com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.control.KEY_EVENT

How can I fire up the action-menu?

I have seen the notification API example and the action menu seems to be configured in the ConfigurationInformation:

```
@Override
public ContentValues getExtensionRegistrationConfiguration() 
{
    Log.d(NuExtensionService.LOG_TAG, "getExtensionRegistrationConfiguration");

    String iconHostapp = ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.icon);
    String iconExtension = ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.icon_extension);
    String iconExtension48 = ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.icon_extension48);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.CONFIGURATION_ACTIVITY, NuPreferenceActivity.class.getName());
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.CONFIGURATION_TEXT, mContext.getString(R.string.configuration_text));
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.NAME, mContext.getString(R.string.extension_name));
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.EXTENSION_KEY, NuExtensionService.EXTENSION_KEY);
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.HOST_APP_ICON_URI, iconHostapp);
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.EXTENSION_ICON_URI, iconExtension);
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.EXTENSION_48PX_ICON_URI, iconExtension48);
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.NOTIFICATION_API_VERSION, getRequiredNotificationApiVersion());
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.PACKAGE_NAME, mContext.getPackageName());

    values.put(Notification.SourceColumns.ACTION_1, mContext.getString(R.string.action_event_1));
    values.put(Notification.SourceColumns.ACTION_2, mContext.getString(R.string.action_event_2));
    values.put(Notification.SourceColumns.ACTION_3, mContext.getString(R.string.action_event_3));
    values.put(Notification.SourceColumns.ACTION_ICON_1, ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.actions_1));
    values.put(Notification.SourceColumns.ACTION_ICON_2, ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.actions_2));
    values.put(Notification.SourceColumns.ACTION_ICON_3, ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.actions_3));

    return values;
}
```

Does this mean the action menu is only available for notification-based apps?

Thanks,

Andrej

Comment: Ahhh I found it. For others: One can send the intent Control.Intents.CONTROL_MENU_SHOW to the host in the onKey() method.

Comment: Put that as an answer then you can accept it in a couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

Ahhhh found it... For others: One can send the intent Control.Intents.CONTROL_MENU_SHOW to the host in the onKey() method. The intent takes a list of action menu items (icons or texts).